Find largest value in array of multi-dimensional array, with different object names
Here is the current code and a section of the larger array:


function Initialize() {
    ARR[127][1][0] = {name:"Gl", ss:["Z0",127,"B0",1,[58,0]], delay:{first:60, term:220, slow:240, med:188, fast:188}};
    ARR[127][127][0] = {name:"Gl Co", ss:["Z0",127,"B0",127,[58,0]], delay:{first:60, term:220, slow:240, med:188, fast:188}};
    ARR[127][1][6] = {name:"Gl El", ss:["Z0",127,"B0",1,[58,6]], delay:{first:60, term:310, slow:360, med:245, fast:145}};
    ARR[127][127][6] = {name:"Gl El Co", ss:["Z0",127,"B0",127,[58,6]], delay:{first:60, term:310, slow:330, med:245, fast:145}}
}

var ARR = new Array(128);
for (let val1 = 0; val1 < ARR.length; val1++) {
  ARR[val1] = new Array(128);
  for (let val2 = 0; val2 < ARR[val1].length; val2++) {
    ARR[val1][val2] = new Array(128);
    for (let val3 = 0; val3 < ARR[val1][val2].length; val3++) {
      ARR[val1][val2][val3] = [];
    }
  }
}

Initialize();

var maxValue = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < ARR.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < ARR[i].length; j++) {
    for (let k = 0; k < ARR[i][j].length; k++) {
      for (let l = 0; l < ARR[i][j][k].length; l++) {
        maxValue = Math.max(...Object.values(ARR[i][j][k].delay))
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(maxValue);



I'm looking to find the largest delay value for objects: first, term, slow, med and fast, from all array elements. In this case the largest value is 360.
I have looked at different methods but they all seem to be for object arrays with the same object, but each object in .delay has a different name (first, term, slow, med and fast).

Math.max(...Object.values(element.delay)) will find the maximum value of any value in the object.

Oops, fixed the typo. Yes, the max of any of the property values of .delay, of all lines.

Then use a nested loop to iterate over all the elements of the array, to get the maximum of that.

@Barmar something like this? ... is just giving me '0' I'm sure I'm missing something simple. https://jsfiddle.net/hsf5enrp/

You'll want to make maxValue an array and push the result you're currently assigning to maxValue into it. Then once all the loops are done, do a Math.max(....maxValue).

@HereticMonkey thank you, working: https://jsfiddle.net/hsf5enrp/

You could just take what you have, make maxValue into an array to capture each loop's calculation, the take the max of that:


function Initialize() {
    ARR[127][1][0] = {name:"Gl", ss:["Z0",127,"B0",1,[58,0]], delay:{first:60, term:220, slow:240, med:188, fast:188}};
    ARR[127][127][0] = {name:"Gl Co", ss:["Z0",127,"B0",127,[58,0]], delay:{first:60, term:220, slow:240, med:188, fast:188}};
    ARR[127][1][6] = {name:"Gl El", ss:["Z0",127,"B0",1,[58,6]], delay:{first:60, term:310, slow:360, med:245, fast:145}};
    ARR[127][127][6] = {name:"Gl El Co", ss:["Z0",127,"B0",127,[58,6]], delay:{first:60, term:310, slow:330, med:245, fast:145}}
}

var ARR = new Array(128);
for (let val1 = 0; val1 < ARR.length; val1++) {
  ARR[val1] = new Array(128);
  for (let val2 = 0; val2 < ARR[val1].length; val2++) {
    ARR[val1][val2] = new Array(128);
    for (let val3 = 0; val3 < ARR[val1][val2].length; val3++) {
      ARR[val1][val2][val3] = [];
    }
  }
}

Initialize();

var maxValue = [];

for (let i = 0; i < ARR.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < ARR[i].length; j++) {
    for (let k = 0; k < ARR[i][j].length; k++) {
      if (ARR[i][j][k].delay) {
        maxValue.push(Math.max(...Object.values(ARR[i][j][k].delay)));
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(Math.max(...maxValue));



... but that's boring :). Let's mix it up a bit. Details in the comments, some links to some articles:
Array.from
Array.prototype.reduce


function Initialize() {
    ARR[127][1][0] = {name:"Gl", ss:["Z0",127,"B0",1,[58,0]], delay:{first:60, term:220, slow:240, med:188, fast:188}};
    ARR[127][127][0] = {name:"Gl Co", ss:["Z0",127,"B0",127,[58,0]], delay:{first:60, term:220, slow:240, med:188, fast:188}};
    ARR[127][1][6] = {name:"Gl El", ss:["Z0",127,"B0",1,[58,6]], delay:{first:60, term:310, slow:360, med:245, fast:145}};
    ARR[127][127][6] = {name:"Gl El Co", ss:["Z0",127,"B0",127,[58,6]], delay:{first:60, term:310, slow:330, med:245, fast:145}}
}

// Use Array.from, with its map function, to create the three dimensional array:
var ARR = Array.from(
  {length:128}, 
  () => Array.from(
    {length:128}, 
    () => Array.from(
      {length: 128}, 
      () => []
    )
  )
);

Initialize();
// I don't really know why the last array is initialized to an array, since you set them to objects in Initialize,
// but whatever.
console.log(ARR[127][127])

// Then we use a little multi-level reduce to get the answer:
const maxValue = ARR.reduce(
  (aggr, curr) => Math.max(aggr, curr.reduce(
    (agg, cur) => Math.max(agg, cur.reduce(
      (ag, cu) => Math.max(ag, (Array.isArray(cu) ? 0 : Math.max(...Object.values(cu.delay)))),
      0)), 
    0)), 
  0);

console.log(maxValue);




Thanks for these options. I'm always interested in something that's not boring. Re: Initialize - if I don't add the Initialize(); line I get 'infinity' for the first snippet and 0 for the second (in JSFiddle).


You need to compare the existing maxValue with the maximum from the current .delay object.
You should initialize all the elements to objects, not arrays.
You need to check if the current element has a .delay property.
You had an extra nested loop (for let l ...) that wasn't needed. You never used l.



function Initialize() {
    ARR[127][1][0] = {name:"Gl", ss:["Z0",127,"B0",1,[58,0]], delay:{first:60, term:220, slow:240, med:188, fast:188}};
    ARR[127][127][0] = {name:"Gl Co", ss:["Z0",127,"B0",127,[58,0]], delay:{first:60, term:220, slow:240, med:188, fast:188}};
    ARR[127][1][6] = {name:"Gl El", ss:["Z0",127,"B0",1,[58,6]], delay:{first:60, term:310, slow:360, med:245, fast:145}};
    ARR[127][127][6] = {name:"Gl El Co", ss:["Z0",127,"B0",127,[58,6]], delay:{first:60, term:310, slow:330, med:245, fast:145}}
}

var ARR = new Array(128);
for (let val1 = 0; val1 < ARR.length; val1++) {
  ARR[val1] = new Array(128);
  for (let val2 = 0; val2 < ARR[val1].length; val2++) {
    ARR[val1][val2] = new Array(128);
    for (let val3 = 0; val3 < ARR[val1][val2].length; val3++) {
      ARR[val1][val2][val3] = {};
    }
  }
}

Initialize();

var maxValue = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < ARR.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < ARR[i].length; j++) {
    for (let k = 0; k < ARR[i][j].length; k++) {
      if (ARR[i][j][k].delay) {
        maxValue = Math.max(maxValue, ...Object.values(ARR[i][j][k].delay));
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(maxValue);




Actually, after giving it a good thought, it can be implemented even in a simpler manner compared to previous answer. The difference here is that we can leverage array and flatMap() to avoid another lookup of a max value from local ones (as in previous answer).
const ARR_SIZE = 128;

// Initialize the ARR 3D array with nulls for uninitialized entries
const ARR = Array.from({ length: ARR_SIZE }, () =>
    Array.from({ length: ARR_SIZE }, () =>
        Array.from({ length: ARR_SIZE }, () => null)
    )
);


let initializedEntriesFunctional = [];

function InitializeFunctional() {
    const entries = [
        {
            x: 127, y: 1, z: 0,
            data: { name: "Gl", ss: ["Z0", 127, "B0", 1, [58, 0]], delay:{ first: 60, term: 220, slow: 240, med: 188, fast: 188 }
        }
    ]

    entries.forEach(entry => {
        // Populate the ARR array with the data object
        ARR[entry.x][entry.y][entry.z] = entry.data;

        // Track only the delay objects for efficient processing
        initializedEntriesFunctional.push(entry.data.delay);
    });
}

// Execute the initialization
InitializeFunctional();


function findMaxDelayFunctional(initializedDelays) {
    // Extract all numerical delay values and flatten them into a single array
    const allDelays = initializedDelays.flatMap(delayObj =>
        Object.values(delayObj).filter(val => typeof val === 'number')
    );

    // Use Math.max to find the largest delay value
    return Math.max(...allDelays);
}

const maximumDelayFunctional = findMaxDelayFunctional(initializedEntriesFunctional);
console.log("The maximum delay using Functional Programming is:", maximumDelayFunctional);


As colleagues rightly mentioned in the comments, you need to leverage three things:

Create an array or map (in this version of the implementation) to keep track only of the delay values
Map is used to keep serialized coordinates as keys (x,y,z) and
values are corresponding data objects. It will allow you to avoid
nested arrays and use the capabilities of Map to make an
efficient lookup.
Leverage Math.max function to find the maximum in an subset

InitializeMap function:
Creates a transformed set with key as coordinates string and corresponding value.
function InitializeMap() {
    const entries = [
        { x: 127, y: 1, z: 0, data: {name:"Gl", ss:["Z0",127,"B0",1,[58,0]], delay:{first:60, term:220, slow:240, med:188, fast:188}}},
        { x: 127, y: 127, z: 0, data: {name:"Gl Co", ss:["Z0",127,"B0",127,[58,0]], delay:{first:60, term:220, slow:240, med:188, fast:188}}},
        { x: 127, y: 1, z: 6, data: {name:"Gl El", ss:["Z0",127,"B0",1,[58,6]], delay:{first:60, term:310, slow:360, med:245, fast:145}}},
        { x: 127, y: 127, z: 6, data: {name:"Gl El Co", ss:["Z0",127,"B0",127,[58,6]], delay:{first:60, term:310, slow:330, med:245, fast:145}}}
    ];

    entries.forEach(entry => {
        const key = `${entry.x},${entry.y},${entry.z}`;
        ARR_Map.set(key, entry.data.delay); // Store only delay objects
    });
}

Search Max Value
Iterate over the transformed map and search the max value within each set. Then find the largest value of all.
// Function to find the maximum delay using Map
function findMaxDelayUsingMap(arrMap) {
    let maxDelay = -Infinity;
    for (let delayObj of arrMap.values()) {
        const localMax = Math.max(...Object.values(delayObj).filter(val => typeof val === 'number'));
        if (localMax > maxDelay) {
            maxDelay = localMax;
        }
    }
    return maxDelay;
}

Complete code example:
// Initialize a Map to store only initialized entries
const ARR_Map = new Map();

// Modified Initialize function to use Map
function InitializeMap() {
    const entries = [
        { x: 127, y: 1, z: 0, data: {name:"Gl", ss:["Z0",127,"B0",1,[58,0]], delay:{first:60, term:220, slow:240, med:188, fast:188}}},
        { x: 127, y: 127, z: 0, data: {name:"Gl Co", ss:["Z0",127,"B0",127,[58,0]], delay:{first:60, term:220, slow:240, med:188, fast:188}}},
        { x: 127, y: 1, z: 6, data: {name:"Gl El", ss:["Z0",127,"B0",1,[58,6]], delay:{first:60, term:310, slow:360, med:245, fast:145}}},
        { x: 127, y: 127, z: 6, data: {name:"Gl El Co", ss:["Z0",127,"B0",127,[58,6]], delay:{first:60, term:310, slow:330, med:245, fast:145}}}
    ];

    entries.forEach(entry => {
        const key = `${entry.x},${entry.y},${entry.z}`;
        ARR_Map.set(key, entry.data.delay); // Store only delay objects
    });
}
 
InitializeMap();

// Function to find the maximum delay using Map
function findMaxDelayUsingMap(arrMap) {
    let maxDelay = -Infinity;
    for (let delayObj of arrMap.values()) {
        const localMax = Math.max(...Object.values(delayObj).filter(val => typeof val === 'number'));
        if (localMax > maxDelay) {
            maxDelay = localMax;
        }
    }
    return maxDelay;
}

let maximumDelayMap = findMaxDelayUsingMap(ARR_Map);
console.log("The maximum delay using Map is:", maximumDelayMap);

